# Microsoft Cognitive services subscription not working

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to use Microsoft Cognitive Services Academic Knowledge Project but am running into issues.

On my account page, it shows I have two active keys:
[image]

However, when I access the API website, I receive this notice:
[image]

Clicking the "Products" link and selecting "Project Academic Knowledge" takes me to here:
[image]

But after clicking "Subscribe", I get this page[image]:

Any help from a member of the support team would be highly appreciated. This has been going on for many days now.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try from an incognito browser? I get errors when signing in with my Github account.

Comment: No luck with incognito